# How to run Django function in Pycharm?

Tags: django, pycharm

I have some internal utilities I want to develop for my Django project. These are utilities that I need to run mostly in my DEV environment, not in production.

I want to be able to call these from my PyDev IDE or Terminal. Is there a way to call functionality in my Django project without creating a view and using a URL to access it?

I've done several Google searches, but nothing is coming up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the "Python Console" on Pycharm, it will automatically set django up and then you can basically do anything you could do on a Django view. You can write your function anywhere and import and call them. To do the setup manually, you'll need these for lines of code after launching a Python interpreter:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'path.to.your.settings') 
import django
django.setup()

# Write code using Django models here
```

Comment: @IşıkKaplan didn't know about manage.py shell before, I guess Pycharm's python console is basically using "manage,py shell".

Answer (score 0):

you could import them to your PyCharm console starting script. In settings under: Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console -> Python Console -> Starting script